# When clicked play button automatically play the video in fullscreen mode

Tags: html, html5-video

I'd like to play the video automatically in fullscreen mode when clicked the play button.
So far, I have to click two buttons (go to fullscreen and play).
Is there some html attribute that can join these two actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a single attribute for this, but you can solve this with JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById("videoplayer").addEventListener("playing", event => {
    const player = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
    if (player.requestFullscreen) 
        player.requestFullscreen();
    else if (player.webkitRequestFullscreen) 
        player.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    else if (player.msRequestFullScreen) 
      player.msRequestFullScreen();
})
```

```html
<video id="videoplayer" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" controls></video>
```

Please note, that it doesn't work in this snippet environment.

Comment: Could you please write me, how to add the event listener to every element with class name "videoplayer"? Thank you